# Create a clickable event after a path has been clicked on the same path?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hi everyone I am currently in the process of making a DIV create on being clicked when a path from an SVG is clicked. I have the function working but now I run into the issue where when I click another path it just opens up a new div rather than update the information in the div already created. This is an example of what I have now for the JavaScript

```
var fakeObject = {"One": {"givenName": "Joshua"}, "Two": {"givenName": "James"}}

console.log(fakeObject)

$("path").on("click", function(e){
    var pathID = e.target.id.split('_');
  console.log(pathID)
  createDiv(pathID[1]);
});

function createDiv(value){
    $("#DOM").append(`
    <div>
        <p>${fakeObject[value].givenName}</p>
    </div>
  `)
}
```

I know my path function will always fire when a path is clicked so I'm not sure how I would rewrite it to either close the div when clicking a new path but preferably just change the elements within the div when clicking a new path. For the HTML an example would look like this.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path id ="Path_One" d="M10,60 L50,10 90,60" />'
  <path id="Path_Two" d="M20,30 L10,130 20,30" />
</svg>
<div id="DOM">
  <p>
    This is a test div
  </p>
</div>
```

Currently whenever a path on the SVG is clicked it just adds a new div instead of updating when clicking on another object. My thought process would be to close the div when clicking a new path and then opening a new one but that wouldn't be necessary if you could update the div with the new information.

Answer (score 0):

Hey :) you can give your div an id and then check if it exists with length. If it exists, just fill in the new stuff with .html.

```
    function createDiv(value){
      if($('#divname').length == 0){   
        $(document.createElement('div')).attr('id', 'divname')
      }
      $('#divname').html(<p>...</p>)                         
     }
```